# no such file or directory after redirection - simple command line program

Tags: c, linux, redirect, command-line

Im programming a shell. This is a small piece of it that handles redirects. I only included the snippet that is causing the error. This portion of the program is supposed to take a command/argument line and execute the line accordingly. The wc < junk > junk2 is an example of a command line input and for some reason when i execute the line its producing that error junk: >: open: No such file or directory.  The rest of the program functions fine but its breaking here.

: wc < junk > junk2

```
junk: >: open: No such file or directory

   1       4      31 junk2
   1       4      31 total
```

I briefly had it working as intended but for some reason I must have lost a piece of the puzzle because it's broken once again.

Ive looked at my array values and they are as expected. For some clarification I'm using a copy of the arguments array so the original is unchanged by setting the argument copy value to NULL. Im setting the argument copy value to null so the loop doesn't repeatedly use a redirection.

If you have any advise or see the problem that I apparently can't it would be appreciated.

```
    while (arguments[i] != NULL)
                        {


                            if ((strcmp(argumentsCopy[i], "<") == 0))
                            {
                                if ((access(argumentsCopy[i + 1], R_OK) == -1))
                                {
                                    printf("Cannot open %s for input\n", argumentsCopy[i + 1]);
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    redirect = 1;
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    int fd = open(argumentsCopy[i + 1], O_RDONLY);
                                    dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                                    close(fd);
                                    argumentsCopy[i] = NULL;
                                    redirect = 1;
                                    execvp(command, &arguments[i + 1]);
                                }

                            }
                            if ((strcmp(argumentsCopy[i], ">") == 0))
                            {


                                int fd = open(argumentsCopy[ i + 1], O_RDWR);
                                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                                close(fd);
                                argumentsCopy[i] = NULL;
                                redirect = 1;  // avoid repeat use of redirection symbol in arguments array
                                execvp(command, &arguments[i + 1]);
                            }

                            i++;
                        }
                        if (redirect == 0)
                        {

                            execvp(command, execArgs);  //execArgs is entire command w/ arguments
                        }
                        exit 0; //default if error occurred.
```

Comment: Please post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: im programming a shell so this is a small piece of it that handles redirects. I only included the snippet that is causing the error. This portion of the program is supposed to take a command/argument line and execute the line accordingly. The wc < junk > junk2   is an example of a command line input and for some reason when i execute the line its producing that error junk: >: open: No such file or directory the rest of the program functions fine but its breaking here.

Comment: no clue if it's related, but you should check if your `open` calls succeed

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those details.  They're important, but they won't be seen down here in the comments.  (For example, I read "[I'm] writing a simple shell script..." and wondered why you were posting C code instead of a shell script.  You don't actually _say_ you're creating your own shell.  That makes a huge difference.)

Comment: i added that file open check. Didnt solve it but probably good to have.Also clarified the question some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you're not correctly using the `execvp` function. Once a call to `execvp` (or any call in the `exec` family) succeeds, the execution of the current program terminates and is replaced by the program you are `exec`ing. Thus, control flow should never proceed past an `execvp` call unless that call failed. Therefore, you cannot call `execvp` until you are sure both the `stdin` and `stdout` file descriptors have been properly redirected (in the case that you have both input and output redirection). From your code sample, it appears you call `execvp` once either one is detected, which means your shell can only redirect input **or** output, not both.

However, that is not the source of the error you're receiving. Consider the input `wc < junk > junk2`. Based on the information you provided, the command and arguments array will be populated as follows:

```
command = "wc"
arguments[0] = ">"
arguments[1] = "junk"
arguments[2] = "<"
arguments[3] = "junk2"
arguments[4] = NULL
```

When `i = 0`, the first if-statement will be taken, opening the file descriptor and performing `execvp` with the parameters `command` and `&arguments[i+1]`. These correspond to the file to be executed and the `argv` array passed to that function's main method respectively. In this case, the command is `wc` and the args are `{ "junk", "<", "junk2", NULL }` (as this is the value of the null terminated array beginning at `&arguments[i+1]`). On Unix systems, it is conventional for the first argument (`argv[0]`) to be the name of the current program. Thus the actual command line arguments begin at `argv[1]` (see [Program Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) for documentation). From `wc`'s perspective, the command line arguments it should process are `{ "<", "junk2", NULL }` after it processes what it believes to be its program name, `argv[0]`, or `junk`.

`wc` takes as arguments the list of files it will process. In this case, it believes that list to be `<` and `junk2`, as `"<"` is an operator recognized by bash and other shells, not the executing program. Thus, `wc` (which believes its name is `junk` because of `argv[0]`) attempts to open `<` as an input file and fails, printing the message:

```
junk: >: open: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In terms of the first section there are other portions of the program that handle child and background processes so the execvp calls can be continuously made.

Comment: In the code segment you have provided, there is no child process. A child process is created by `fork`, not `exec`. `exec` replaces the currently executing program in the same process.

Comment: If i'm reading the second part correctly I need to maintain a format to the execvp calls during the loop that matches something line `execvp([command], [command, arg1, arg2, arg3 ...] )` and then when the second redirection is found it would look line `exec([ wc ], [ wc , > ,  junk2 ])` ?

Comment: yeah my fork statement is above this snippet. Im new to SO, Im not really sure what the protocol should be regarding breadth of code provided.

Comment: That's half the problem. When you make the exec call, both input and output should be already redirected, and the `exec` call should be `execvp(["wc"], ["wc"])`. There should be no remaining redirect logic when `exec` is called.

Comment: Also, "execvp calls can be continuously made" is not a true statement. When you make an `execvp` call, the control flow of the current program terminates. If you place a statement after an `execvp` call and that call succeeds, it will never be reached, whether you forked before or not.

Comment: Ok fixed it! I edited those execvp calls to take the right command values and then I placed the calls following both potential redirections so as not to ignore the second redirection. Thanks for your help. Sunk a serious amount of time into this one.